# Finding all possible Combination of Pairs in a list

Tags: java, permutation, combinations, calculus

I am experimenting with the implementation of Integration by parts and am trying to pull out all the possible `u` and `dv` pairs from a list of all the things multiplied together. The code provided is my method, except the Function objects have been replaced with strings for readability and so that people could run it out of context.

```
ArrayList<String> funcObjects = giveList(CALC.MULTIPLY, function);//populate this any way you like

//all the pairs are stored in a matrix
int pairCounter = 0;
String[][] udvPairs = new String[funcObjects.size() * funcObjects.size()][2];
//for (int skip = 0; skip < 1; skip++) {
//commented out for sake of a better solution
for (int i = 0; i < funcObjects.size() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println("i=" + i);
    //System.out.println(function.size());
    for (int j = 0; j < funcObjects.size() - i; j++) {
        System.out.println("j=" + j);
        CalcObject u = "1";
        CalcObject dv = "1";
        for (int start = j; start <= j + i; start++) {
            //this loop here is what is generating my u.
            //note that it goes in order and therefore cannot
            //account for items that are not next to each other in the list
            //my question is how to add a fix for this
            u = u + " * " + funcObjects.get(start);
        }
        for (int end = 0; end < j; end++) {
            dv = dv + " * " + funcObjects.get(end);
        }
        for (int end = j + i + 1; end < funcObjects.size(); end++) {
            dv = dv + " * " + funcObjects.get(end);
        }

        System.out.println("Pair " + pairCounter + "; u: " + u.toString() + " dv: " + dv.toString());
        udvPairs[pairCounter][0] = u;
        udvPairs[pairCounter][1] = dv;
        pairCounter++;
    }
}
```

This is my code so far. The combinations it gives me are correct, but it does not give me all the combinations. For example:

`x * SIN(x) * COS(x)`

i.e. the list passed in being `["x","SIN(x)","COS(x)"]`

will give me

```
i=0  
j=0  
Pair 0; u: x dv: SIN(x) * COS(x)  
j=1   
Pair 1; u: SIN(x) dv: x * COS(x)  
j=2  
Pair 2; u: COS(x) dv: x * SIN(x)  
i=1  
j=0  
Pair 3; u: x * SIN(x) dv: COS(x)  
j=1  
Pair 4; u: SIN(x) * COS(x) dv: x
```

It is skipping u: `x * COS(x) dv: SIN(x)`

So my question is, anyone have an idea how to make it also account for combinations in which the parts are not next to each other? The program is not throwing any errors, I just don't know how to finish implementing what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: What values of `i` and `j` correspond to the case you're missing?

Comment: i would have to be 1 in order for there to be 2 strings for u, and j is just incrementing where it starts counting from i.e. start from index j.

Comment: I guess then the question is why you're not reaching the right values of `i` and `j`. (I'm trying to help you solve your own problem. ;) )

Comment: well its not necessarily the wrong values...

Comment: I just need a way to skip over values in the list so that I can get more combinations. that is why the very first loop with the skip variable is commented out (failed attempt)

Comment: I figured it out, question closed I guess. I'll answer my own question when the annoying 10 hour timer runs out.

Comment: Good to hear! (Best possible outcome, actually.) Submit your answer, accept it, and if it's helpful to future readers I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to make it work:

```
ArrayList<String[]> udvPairs = new ArrayList<>();
String[] temp = new String[2];
String notOne = "1";
for (int i = 0; i < funcObjects.size(); i++) {
    notOne = notOne += funcObjects.get(i);
}
temp[0] = "1";
temp[1] = notOne;
udvPairs.add(temp);
temp = new String[2];
temp[1] = "1";
temp[0] = notOne;
udvPairs.add(temp);
for (int i = 0; i < funcObjects.size() - 1; i++) {
    //System.out.println("i=" + i);
    //System.out.println(function.size());
    for (int j = 0; j < funcObjects.size() - i; j++) {
        //System.out.println("j=" + j);
        for (int skip = 0; skip < funcObjects.size() - i - j; skip++) {
            //System.out.println("skip=" + skip);
            String u = "1";
            String dv = "1";
            u += funcObjects.get(j);
            for (int start = j + skip + 1; start <= j + i + skip; start++) {
                u += ufuncObjects.get(start);
            }
            for (int end = 0; end < j; end++) {
                dv += funcObjects.get(end);
            }
            for (int end = j + 1; end < j + skip + 1; end++) {
                dv += funcObjects.get(end);
            }
            for (int end = j + i + 1 + skip; end < funcObjects.size(); end++) {
                dv += funcObjects.get(end);
            }
            //}
            //System.out.println("Pair " + pairCounter + "; u: " + u.toString() + " dv: " + dv.toString());
            temp = new String[2];
            temp[0] = u;
            temp[1] = dv;
            boolean addIt = true;
            for (int x = 0; x < udvPairs.size(); x++) {
                if (udvPairs.get(x)[0].equals(u) && udvPairs.get(x)[1].equals(dv)) {
                    addIt = false;
                    x = udvPairs.size();
                }
            }
            if (addIt) {
                udvPairs.add(temp);
            }
            //pairCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```